# Function called from external .c file does nothing

Tags: c

I am trying to setup a function for a mosquitto pub command.  This command is held in a separate .c file from the main .c file.  Everything compiles fine but when I call the function (called within the external .c file) from within the external .c file nothing happens.  Conversely if I invoke the function in it's own compiled program with no external .c file, the function acts as it should.  Realizing that I am doing something wrong, I tried to do something simple by a simple printf function and calling it in the external .c file and it compiles fine but still doesn't print my data.  What am I doing wrong?  I have the function defined in the .h also.

```
void mosquittoto(void)
{
  struct mosquitto *mosq = NULL;

  // Initialize the Mosquitto library
  mosquitto_lib_init();

  // Create a new Mosquitto runtime instance with a random client ID,
  //  and no application-specific callback data.  
  mosq = mosquitto_new (NULL, true, NULL);
  if (!mosq)
    {
    fprintf (stderr, "Can't initialize Mosquitto library\n");
    exit (-1);
    }

  mosquitto_username_pw_set (mosq, MQTT_USERNAME, MQTT_PASSWORD);

  // Establish a connection to the MQTT server. Do not use a keep-alive ping
  int ret = mosquitto_connect (mosq, MQTT_HOSTNAME, MQTT_PORT, 0);
  if (ret)
    {
    fprintf (stderr, "Can't connect to Mosquitto server\n");
    exit (-1);
    }

  int i;
  char text[20];
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    //sprintf (text, "Hello, World %d", i);
    // Publish the message to the topic
    ret = mosquitto_publish (mosq, NULL, MQTT_TOPIC,
      strlen (epc4pub), epc4pub, 0, false);
    if (ret)
      {
      fprintf (stderr, "Can't publish to Mosquitto server\n");
      exit (-1);
      }
    }

  // We need a short delay here, to prevent the Mosquitto library being
  //  torn down by the operating system before all the network operations
  //  are finished.
  sleep (1);

  // Tidy up
  mosquitto_disconnect (mosq);
  mosquitto_destroy (mosq);
  mosquitto_lib_cleanup();
}
```

I have the function defined in the .h file as:

```
void mosquittoto(void);
```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: What is the line you use to compile your program?

Comment: Hi Vlad.  I am compiling in three steps.  FIrst I am compiling the external c file to a .o.  Then I archive that file.  After that I use  `sudo gcc -I /home/pi/RFID_TEST/archives/ IRI_LT_Intro.c IRI.a ipj_util.a platform_linux.o -o test -lmosquitto -lssl -lcrypto -pthread -lcares -DPB_FIELD_16BIT -Wall -Wno-missing-field-initializers -lc`  ipj_util.a is the archive file name containing the code.

Comment: Ok, let's say you are have your main.c file and the code from your question is in a file called external.c. You compile external.c to external.o. After that are you sure that you are linking external.o to main when you compile your main? That is do you do:
gcc external.c -c -o external.o and then gcc external.o main.c -o myprogram.bin

Comment: main.c calls other code from the external.c and that code all works great.  A separate issue I am having is that if I call the command in external.c from main.c I can't get it to compile.  I only share that issue because it may be related.  For my question however, I am calling the command in external.c from within external.c  So to answer your question, I am pretty sure everything is linked OK.  Thank you very much for your help Vlad!

Comment: Do you link to the object file or not? Pretty sure does you no good. If you aren't sure, make sure.

Comment: Also, my main problem stems from the example library from the device I am trying to communicate with.  It is written very confusing and commented very little.  When I compile, unless I archive all the .o files included in the library main.c won't compile.  I definitely link to the .a files when I compile.

Comment: "if I call the command in external.c from main.c I can't get it to compile"
What's the error?
What do you mean: "does nothing"? Have you tried looking under a debugger? What happens when you call the function? Are you sure you call it in the first place?
Can you reproduce the problem with a simplified very basic example?

Comment: Your complaint is "it still doesn't print my data" - But your code does not print any data, you only have output in places where something goes wrong. What do you actually expect the program to do? It connects to the MB and publishes to a topic - You don't seem to subscribe to any topic, so what do you expect to receive?